# GIN Index has O(N^2) complexity for array overlap operator?

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

I ran into an issue with using the && array operator on a GIN index of mine. Basically I have a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM example
WHERE keys && ARRAY[1,2,3,...]
```

This works fine for a small number of array elements (N) in the array literal, but gets really slow as N gets bigger in what appears to be O(N^2) complexity.

However, from studying the GIN data structure as described by the docs, it seems that the performance for this could be O(N). In fact, it's possible to coerce the query planner into an O(N) plan like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (example.id) *
FROM unnest(ARRAY[1,2,3,...]) key
JOIN example ON keys && ARRAY[key]
```

In order to illustrate this better, I've created a jupyter notebook that populates an example table, show the query plans for both queries, and most importantly benchmarks them and plots a time vs array size (N) graph.

https://github.com/felixge/pg-slow-gin/blob/master/pg-slow-gin.ipynb

[image: query performance]

Please help me understand what causes the O(N^2) performance for query 1 and if query 2 is the best way to work around this issue.

Thanks
Felix Geisendörfer

PS: I'm using Postgres 10, but also verified that this problem exists with Postgres 11.

I've also [posted this question](https://www.postgresql-archive.org/GIN-Index-has-O-N-2-complexity-for-array-overlap-operator-tt6037340.html) on the postgres performance mailing list, but unfortunately didn't get any answer.

Comment: Like most things the most simple is not always the best.. But you should show table structures and a explains in performance questions

Comment: @RaymondNijland I've provided all this information in the Jupyter notebook mentioned in my post: https://github.com/felixge/pg-slow-gin/blob/master/pg-slow-gin.ipynb . PTAL

Comment: high number of poeple on stackoverflow don't click external links..

Comment: @RaymondNijland huh? Why is that?

Comment: Well i think it's because the first query always checks  the array elements in the table vs  "large" array sizes vs the second query whichs checks the array elements in the table vs one array element always because of the unnest... Dont forget rdbms should be running more optimized when using it relational which the second query looks like to enforce better on PostgreSQL.

Comment: @RaymondNijland I was asking why stackoverflow people don't click external links ;). Anyway, I think your answer doesn't really answer my question about what happens internally. I'd like to understand this down to the details.

Comment: "I was asking why stackoverflow people don't click external links" Oh should i remove the last comment then?.. What do you think of trust issues or they find the information about a question should be on one page only.. A "trusted" domain link would help i geuss

Comment: "Anyway, I think your answer doesn't really answer my question about what happens internally. I'd like to understand this down to the details. ".  Good luck best way to find out is looking into the PostgreSQL source code.. Besides mine comment wasn't really a answer it's more a educated "guess"

Comment: Did you try `ALTER INDEX ... SET (fastupdate = off);` and then `VACUUM` the table? Perhaps a long pending list is the problem.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe good idea. I just updated my notebook to create the index with `fastupdate = off` and re-ran the example. But unfortunately it made no difference, so I don't think this is related to the pending list.

Comment: Also are you sure caching also didn't influenced the second query because off PostgreSQL caching could have speed up the second query.. Iám wondering if you get different becnhmark results when you turn PostgreSQL off and on again and then run the second query on a "cold" server

Comment: @RaymondNijland no, this is not caching related. I can change the order of queries, and the result is the same. Also even if query 1 was always hitting cold cache, that should only result in a linear performance penalty, not quadratic.

Comment: Well the second line is more or less linear because off that i got the idea the second query might be hitting the cache.. Atleast we can eliminate cache now as a possibility

Comment: After reading this again, several things are unclear to me. 1) do you increase the size of the array in the table *and* the size of the array constant in the query? Because `&&` is certainly O(m*n). 2) In the slow cases, where is the time spent? Can you show an `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` for such a query?

Comment: I am facing similar issue with array overlap. I am trying to upgrade to v10.17 but my array overlap query suddenly became very slow after the upgrade. I've tried to run Analyse on the DB, reindexed all tables, did a vacuum as well. nothing seems to work. @FelixGeisendörfer did you find a solution by any chance?

what's more hard to understand for me is why did it runs fast on v9.6 and now on v10.17 why its so slow all of a sudden. all the documentation I've been reading says that v10+ have a lot of performance upgrades.

Answer (score 1):

you need three things:

```
create extension intarray;
```

then create gist index with operator gist__int_opts

```
CREATE INDEX fgfe
   ON public.arrtest USING gist (keys2 gist__int_ops );
```

drop old index if any.

and voila - your query now uses bitmap index scan:

```
explain SELECT *
FROM arrtest
WHERE  ARRAY[1,2,3,4] && keys2
```

result:

```
Bitmap Heap Scan on arrtest  (cost=4.24..14.92 rows=12 width=104)
  Recheck Cond: ('{1,2,3,4}'::integer[] && keys2)
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on fgfe  (cost=0.00..4.23 rows=12 width=0)
        Index Cond: ('{1,2,3,4}'::integer[] && keys2)
```

[Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/intarray.html)